# Why is my JDBC prepared statement update not updating the database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-update

I am using JDBC to update a row in my MySQL database:

```
    pConnection.setAutoCommit(true); 

    PreparedStatement pstmt = pConnection.prepareStatement("update mg_build_queue " + //
            "set buildsetid=?,locale=?,areacode=?,distversionid=?,platformid=?,version=?," + //
            "priority=?,buildstatus=?,computername=?,buildoutput=?,started=?,finished=?, packageid=?, lockcounter=0 where buildid=?" //
    );

    pstmt.setInt(1, mBuildSet.getId());
    pstmt.setString(2, Locale.localesToString(mLocales, ","));
    pstmt.setString(3, mAreaCode.toString());
    pstmt.setInt(4, mDistVersionId);
    pstmt.setInt(5, mPlatform);
    pstmt.setInt(6, mVersion);
    pstmt.setLong(7, mPriority);
    pstmt.setInt(8, mBuildStatus);
    pstmt.setString(9, mComputerName);
    pstmt.setString(10, mBuildOutput);
    pstmt.setTimestamp(11, timeToTimestamp(mStarted));
    pstmt.setTimestamp(12, timeToTimestamp(mFinished));
    pstmt.setInt(13, mResultPackageId);
    pstmt.setInt(14, mBuildId);

    LOGGER.debug("Updating data for mg_build_queue: " + pstmt);
    pstmt.execute();
    LOGGER.debug("Updated " + pstmt.getUpdateCount() + " rows.");
```

This is generating the following output:

```
2012-05-24 09:54:33,211 [Thread-1] DEBUG com.buildmaster.BuildQueueEntryImpl - Updating data for mg_build_queue: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@35e09eab: update mg_build_queue set buildsetid=201,locale='FR',areacode='XX',distversionid=95,platformid=4604,version=65807,priority=33652480,buildstatus=1,computername='MY_COMPUTER-C:\\BUILDS',buildoutput='',started='2012-05-24 09:54:33',finished='2012-05-24 19:45:27', packageid=0, lockcounter=0 where buildid=122418
2012-05-24 09:54:33,214 [Thread-1] DEBUG com.buildmaster.BuildQueueEntryImpl - Updated 1 rows.
```

I see no exception. If I query for the entry in DBVisualizer, I see only the old value. If I run the command by hand in DBVisualizer (copied and pasted from above), I can see the updated value.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Given that you have autocommit set to true, I would say that you're looking at the wrong database, or at the wrong row.

Comment: Or confusing old and new value, or reverting the operation later with a second call. I agree with Nizet : there doesn't seem to be an error justifying what you see.

Comment: @JBNizet Good thinking to double-check, but I only have one database with that table in it, and carefully copy and paste the build ID into the select statement. Also a spot check of my connection URL looks correct.

Comment: @dystroy I set a breakpoint directly after the LOGGER statement above, so there is no place to revert the statement.

Comment: Is your buildId guaranteed unique ?

Comment: @dystroy Yes, buildid is a unique primary key.

Comment: @BenFlynn - Other than *DBVisualizer*, after update, did you try executing *select ...* from any other interface? If yes, what is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that DBVisualizer is doing some result caching. I disconnected and reconnected using DBVisualizer and can see the update. Thanks to all for their suggestions.

Thanks to a [Hans Bergsten on the DBVisualizer forums](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/message.jspa?messageID=14064), here is how to prevent my issue:

> Tools -> Tool Properties -> Database -> MySQL -> Physical Connection

Change `Transaction Isolation` to `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`.

**NOTE** I also restarted my MySQL database, which I don't think affected things, but is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

calling `pConnection.commit()` is must to reflect changes in database if you explicitly set

`pConnection.setAutoCommit(false)`

Comment: I think you mean it's a must if I set it to false, yes? Auto-commit should auto-commit (i.e. perform a commit) after each statement.

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)

Comment: @rohit - No. *The commit occurs when the statement completes. ... For DML statements, such as Insert, Update or Delete, and DDL statements, the statement is complete as soon as it has finished executing....*. Read javadoc on [`setAutoCommit( ... )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean))

Comment: @rohit - OK. you modified it to `false`.

Comment: @Ravinder I mistakenly wrote 'true'

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by MySQL's default isolation level which is "REPEATABLE READ".

Provided your JDBC statement was committed properly you also need to end the open transaction in DBVisualizer. Any select statement starts a transaction and unless you terminate that you won't see any changes done by other transactions.

Another option is to change the default isolation level to READ COMMITTED and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Weird but this problem stopped when I restarted Eclipse

Answer (score -2):

```
    if(checkInputs() && txt_id.getText() == null)
    {
        String UpdateQuery = null;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        Connection con=getConnection();
        if(ImgPath == null)
        {
            try {
                     UpdateQuery="UPDATE products SET name = ? , price = ? , add_date=? WHERE id=?";
                     ps=con.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);
                      ps.setString(1, txt_name.getText());
                ps.setString(2, txt_price.getText());


                SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String addDate=dateformat.format(btn_date.getDate());
                ps.setString(3, addDate);
                ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText()));
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main_window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                //update with image

                InputStream img=new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath));
                UpdateQuery="UPDATE products SET name = ? , price = ?  ,add_date=? , image = ? WHERE id=?";
                ps=con.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);
                ps.setString(1, txt_name.getText());
                ps.setString(2, txt_price.getText());


                SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String addDate=dateformat.format(btn_date.getDate());
                ps.setString(3, addDate);
                ps.setBlob(4, img);
                ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText()));
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Main_window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"One or more fields are empty or wrong");

    }
```