# Unable to execute update using email address as primary key in Derby

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I looked at these questions and my problem is unique to them.

[JDBC Update Statement not working in Netbeans but working in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949011/jdbc-update-statement-not-working-in-netbeans-but-working-in-sql)

[Why is my JDBC prepared statement update not updating the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742133/why-is-my-jdbc-prepared-statement-update-not-updating-the-database?rq=1)

Whenever I use a valid  'email' to update rows in my user_account table, the statement locks up and then I get the following exception:

**java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: 
A lock could not be obtained within the time requested**

For this input it  works fine:

EMAIL:chris
NAME:null
PHONE:null
ADDRESS:null

When I use the real input:

EMAIL:validEmailWants@someDomain.com
NAME:null
PHONE:null
ADDRESS:null

The failure occurs.

[EDIT]

However, the input below works fine:

EMAIL:chris@localhost.com
NAME:null
PHONE:null
ADDRESS:null

So it can't be the special characters in email addresses that are
causing the problem.

I am using a prepared statement so I am pretty sure I don't need to 'escape' any of the special characters in the email address.  But I could be wrong.

The method is below:

```
public boolean setInfo(InfoBean p){

    ////  NOT USING THE PASSED IN INFOBEAN  //////////
    ////  BECAUSE I HAD TO ISOLATE THE BUG  //////////


    InfoBean proto = new InfoBean();

    //FAIL
    proto.setEmail("validEmailWants@someDomain.com"); 

    //PASS
    //proto.setEmail("chris@localhost.com");


    //PASS
    //proto.setEmail("validEmailHasWanted@someDomain.com");

    // PASS
    //proto.setEmail("validEmailWantsHasWanted@someDomain.com"); 



    System.out.println("EMAIL:"   + proto.getEmail());
    System.out.println("NAME:"    + proto.getName());
    System.out.println("PHONE:"   + proto.getPhoneNumber());
    System.out.println("ADDRESS:" + proto.getAddress());


    Connection c = null;

    try{  
        c = this.dataSource.getConnection();

        String s = "update user_account "
                +  "set name = ?, "
                +  "phone = ?, "
                +  "address = ?, "
                +  "image = ?"
                +  "where email = ?";

        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(s);

        if(proto.getName() == null)
            ps.setString(1, ""); 
        else
            ps.setString(1, proto.getName());


        ps.setString(2, proto.getPhoneNumber());
        ps.setString(3, proto.getAddress());

        BufferedImage image = proto.getImage();
        if(image != null){
            ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", outStream);
            ps.setBlob(4, new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray()));
        }
        else{
            ps.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
        }

        ps.setString(5, proto.getEmail());

        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.close();
        c.close();
        return true;
}
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("\n\n SOME KIND OF EXCEPTION \n\n");
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    finally{
        //System.out.println("\n\n SOME KIND OF EXCEPTION \n\n");
        closeConnection(c);
    }
    return false;

}
```

The database structure is shown below. The underlined words are the primary keys.  The diamonds are relationship sets.  Circles are attributes (the column names).  The squares are tables.

[image]

Below is a printout of the user_account table to compare the passing and failing cases specific attribute values.
[image]

[UPDATE]

I ran a test case where I set the fields to something 
that was NOT NULL, then set the back again to NULL.
(This was on a different email), and there was 
no problems.  There seems to be something 
about that particular email which is causing the 
failure.

Comment: `derby` or `mysql`?

Comment: Looks like a process or query Looks the table `A lock could not be obtained within the time requested `

Comment: Yes, you are correct, however, I am only running a single update.  The only change I am making is whether or not the email = 'chris' or 'validEmailWants@someDomain.com'  both are primary keys in the same table.

Comment: Can you insert (as opposed to update) data containing an email? What is the database structure? Can you quote the prepared statement? Would you like to add more tags, e.g. [mysql]?

Comment: @Yunnosch Derby != mysql, so that is not a relevant suggestion.

Comment: Did you commit when you inserted the row (or otherwise: verify that auto-commit is really true).

Comment: I'll edit the title so its more clear that is it Derby I am using (not SQL).

Comment: Technically, you **are** using SQL.

Comment: Autocommit is true by default according to the documentation.  But I will do a check just to be sure.  Good suggestion.

Comment: Not related to your problem: but are you sure you want to use an email address as your primary key? You are going to run in all kinds of painful situations when a user changes their address.

Comment: I am thinking its a bug in Derby its self. I will try to change my derby version.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel True, the "my" was me jumping ahead in the wrong direction, valid point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I was logging in the user in a separate request (which I forgot about) and not closing the connection properly afterward. 
[image]

(A simple connection.close() in another method fixed the problem).

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, so I am the wrong person. But would not one of the gurus agree, that this question/answer pair is clear and useful? I.e. please consider, based on your expertise, to upvote.

Comment: Its a common mistake.  I am sure that similar cases have been addressed on here.  Though this is a good example of why it is so important to close database connections after your done. (hours of torture for me).